# sharepoint list permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

please help with following task:

i have sharepoint list, all participants see only own records (they are can create, modify and read only own records),

i need to give permissions for two users for editing each other records only, and not allow to see other users records.

is ir possible to do with Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SharePoint tool Called [SharePoint Column & View Permission](http://www.sharepointboost.com/columnpermission.html) is a good way to cope your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  The best solution is to create a seperate list and only give these two people access to this list.  This creates a clean seperation between the "special" users and everyone else.

If you really want to keep everything in one list then you will need to write some custom code to reset the permissions after items are created by these two users.  You will need to break the permission inheritance for these items and remove everyone else permissions.  A little clunky but possible.